# refreshing checkboxes in gui java

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, refresh

i´m here because i´m getting crazy looking always into my code and try figuring out what I did wrong.

Guess I need some help and your new eyes which can help me out.

the problem is... I´m running through a rountine of checkboxes and when a checkbox is clicked a new one will be display. -> that works.
When i´m done I want to click a refresh-button and the checkboxes should be reseted as in the beginning.
To start over again.
But I don´t get it how...

this is the code what listens to the checkboxes...

```
    /** Listens to the check boxes. */
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getItemSelectable();

    if (source == chinButton) {
        System.out.println("Chinbutton Pressed");
        glassesButton.setVisible(true);
        lblPass.setForeground(Color.green);
        chinButton.setEnabled(false);


    } else if (source == glassesButton) {
        System.out.println("GlassesButtonPressed");
        lblNewLabel_5.setForeground(Color.green);
        hairButton.setVisible(true);
        glassesButton.setEnabled(false);

    } else if (source == hairButton) {
        System.out.println("hairButtonPressed");
        teethButton.setVisible(true);
        lblNewLabel_6.setForeground(Color.green);
        hairButton.setEnabled(false);

    } else if (source == teethButton) {
        System.out.println("teethButtonPressed");
        chckbxTested_1.setVisible(true);
        lblPass_1.setForeground(Color.green);
        teethButton.setEnabled(false);

    } else if (source == chckbxTested_1) {
        System.out.println("chckbxTestedButtonPressed");
        lblNewLabel_9.setForeground(Color.green);
        System.out.println("chckbxTestedButtonPressed2");
        chckbxTested_1.setEnabled(false);
        btnSavePdfprint.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

I would really appreciate if there is someone out there who would help me with that issue.

THANKS

Comment: The code you show is not enough to help us.Can you also show how the panel is reset ? And how the buttons are built ?

Comment: “When I’m done I want to click a refresh-button and the checkboxes should be reseted as in the beginning.”  Include whatever code you've written for that refresh button in your question.  You can edit your question using the "edit" link located beneath the shaded keyword rectangles under your question.